# Eclipse (Configuración ventanas)

Tags: eclipse

cómo consigo restablecer las ventanas de eclipse a su configuración predeterminada, o bien, cómo consigo quitar la ruta visible de mi proyecto? 
Os dejo una captura de pantalla :)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para cerrar la ruta te recomiendo reiniciar la perspectiva. Esto hará que la pantalla del IDE se restablezca y se vea como el primer día. Esto no cambia los estilos que tengas añadidos o personalizados, solo cambia la colocación de las ventanas.

Para reiniciar la perspectiva tendrás que ir a "Window" en el menú superior, "Perspective" y "Reset Perspective".

También puedes cambiar de perspectiva si lo desea. 
Espero haberle ayudado.

Un saludo.